# joblib.load() in cluster cannot load files

Tags: python, mpi, pickle, joblib, scikit-image

**Intro**
I am porting some code that run on a regular laptop to a cluster (HPC) with MPI.
What I am dealing with is an embarrassingly parallel problem where I am sending  different file paths to a bunch of workers. Each corresponding file contains one numpy array that have been previously generated using the `joblib.dump()` function with `lzma compression=2`.

**Details**
All the files are saved in the same directory
Example of file list generate by `joblib.dump()`:
- File1.lzma
- File1.lzma_01.npy.z
- File2.lzma
- File2.lzma_01.npy.z

If I pass to the workers the path to the files with .lmza extension (Ex. File1.lzma) `joblib.load()` on the worker cannot load the file and gives me an error. It is the same if I pass the files with .lzma_01.npy.z. My guess is because both files are needed and in case of HPC is not enough that the files sits in the same directory (on the code running in my laptop is enough and the files are properly loaded)

**Questions**
1) Is my hypothesis correct?
2) Is there a way to pass both file paths to `joblib.load()`?
3) Is this a missing functionality and I should reprocess the files and save them with pickle?
4) Am I completely wrong?

Thanks

Comment: When you submit a job via a batch system, there is no guarantee that it starts running in the same directory it was submitted from - try putting an explicit "cd" in your batch script to ensure that you are running in the correct directory (or you could use absolute path names /home/userid/...) Another guess would be that your files are not directly visible from the compute nodes, for example the home filesystem on the login/frontend system may not be mounted on the HPC cluster. Often there will be a special filesystem that is mounted on both systems.

Comment: @DavidHenty as you stated using absolute path was the correct trick.